# Amazon EC2 How Do I Host a PDF File on my Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I am using this guide:
http://codingthis.com/platforms/linux/how-to-host-simple-content-with-amazon-elastic-cloud-computing-ec2/

I have a folder named public_html in my /home/ec2-user directory with a index.html file.

What I have done so far:

```
sudo yum -y install httpd php
sudo chkconfig httpd on
chmod 755 /home/ec2-user  (I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT THIS DOES)
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  (changed DocumentRoot to DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/public_html)
```

Now when I go to my www.mywebsite.com it will hit my index.html file. I tried to put a pdf file in my public_html directory, I tried to go to www.mywebsite.com/pdffile.pdf and it says page not found. How do I host my pdf file on my ec2 instance?

EXTRA:

I have a security group enabled for my instance with rules:

```
ICMP Allow ALL
TCP Allow ALL
UDP Allow ALL
TCP port 80 (Http)
```

Comment: It's very confusing when you add the answer to your question to the end of your question with no notice. You *can* answer your own questions with the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

user848118 answered his/her own question: URLs are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your machine's IP is myipaddress
Put the PDF file in /var/www and browse

http://myipaddress.com/file.pdf

Works for me.