# How do I publicly host a file on my Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Though similar to [Amazon EC2 How Do I Host a PDF File on my Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721582/amazon-ec2-how-do-i-host-a-pdf-file-on-my-instance) this is not a simple case of case sensitivity.

I currently have the file I'd like to be publicly available in /var/www/html which is the DocumentRoot (though note we've also got amazon EBS set up) but nonetheless going to ourinstance/file.pdf gives 404 not found.

I'd like to avoid having to use S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a web server (apache/nginx) and configure it to serve the file (from a domain). In order to do that, you need to setup a virtual host (or its equivalent in nginx).

Once done, you start the server and assuming DNS settings are correctly setup, your file should be served.

I think this question is better suited to be asked on serverfault rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah of course, makes sense. Thanks and thanks for pointing out serverfault.